# Querying the Windows Media Player library

Tags: c#, windows-media-player, wmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access the Windows Media Player library C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163668/access-the-windows-media-player-library-c)

I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically query the Windows Media Player library from a C# program. I don't want to control the media player, just be able to query the index of recordings stored in the library.

Using OleDbConnections I have been able to connect to the Windows SystemIndex to query for various files and conditions, but these searches are across all files in my system and not just those maintained in the WMP library.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

-- Robert

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a whole section on the Media Player SDK - and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562289%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in particular should be of considerable use to you, I hope.